# Weird behaviour from input validation in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS is not setting invalid to true in my project on one page.  It works on other pages.  I created a minimal example with CodePen and it works.  I copy the code verbatim and it doesn't work on my page.  Instead what happens is the value becomes undefined, which is good, but the `form.$invalid` is false.  The CodePen example works just fine, in one of the controllers it works, in this new controller it doesn't.  I am using ui-router so this controller gets injected into the view but so does the other controller that works.  I can't even think what else I might share with you. There's 100s of thousands of lines in this code that I didn't write, but I've been intimate with it for about 2 years now.

I created a minimal working example of a simple field validation with max. Just add three zeroes to the end and observe how the value disappears from underneath and invalid becomes true.  In my project the value disappears but invalid remains false.  I know this is likely not enough information to resolve the issue unless you yourself have had this problem or you can just think of things that might cause it.  I will provide you with whatever you ask except for actual access to the site.

https://codepen.io/bluebaroncanada/pen/abmREVE

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="testController">
  <form name="form" novalidate ng-submit="submit()">
  <input type="number" class="form-control text-right" ng-model="model.someNumber" numeric precision="0" min="0" max="1000" required />
    Invalid: {{form.$invalid}}
  </form>
  {{message}}
  {{model.someNumber}}
</div>
```

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "test";
  $scope.model = {
    someNumber: 5
  };
}]);
```

**Edit: I have another clue**

I sorta got it working, but not fully.

Broken:

```
<input type="number" ...
```

Works:

```
<input type="text" ...
```

Works but they can't use the spin controller and it doesn't prevent them from inputting characters other than numbers.

Comment: My understanding is you need to provide minimum code that reproduces the problem. Is Angularjs version the same?

Comment: Yeah.  I cannot reproduce the problem which is making it impossible to diagnose.  If anyone has any starter tips for deep diving AngularJS's code, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there are 2 possibilities: either `form.$invalid` is not set to false or some code sets it back to true. I will give you a hint how you can debug any such strange things.

Lets add following button to your example:

```
<button ng-click="startDebug()"> Start debug </button>
  
 $scope.startDebug = () => {
    $scope.form._$invalid = $scope.model.form.$invalid;
    Object.defineProperty($scope.model.form, '$invalid', {
      get: function() {return this._$invalid;},
      set: function(val) {this._$invalid = val; console.log('set to ' + val)}
    });
 }
```

After clicking this stupid button, we start recording all changes of `form.$invalid`. You can place breakpoint here and see actual call-tree `$setViewValue -> maxValidator parser -> ...`.

Now you can try same in your actual code that produces error and see what is different.